# What is ateji? Are they different from on'yomi?

Tags: words, ateji, onyomi

can someone please explain me what exactly are ateji and how they differ from on'yomi?
I have been told already, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: What exactly were you “told already”?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky If I may make a guess, something to the effect of: "*on'yomi* is reading *kanji* by sound, *ateji* is reading *kanji* only by their sound value, regardless of meaning". Add to this, "*kun'yomi* is reading *kanji* by their meaning".

Comment: Have you read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ateji)?

Comment: @Skye-AT I think that wikipedia page might not be particularly helpful.  I know what ateji are, but, if I were unfamiliar with the concept or Japanese writing in general and already confused about ateji, I don't think that page would have helped me.   It's perhaps a bit too much information absorb and take in (if that makes sense).

Comment: @A.Ellett Hmm, makes sense. I've just read through that page and yes I think it's a bit too much information too. What I find funny is, the Japanese version of that page doesn't mention Sanskrit... Not even a history at all!

Comment: @Skye-AT  Wow.  I hadn't even thought to look at the Japanese version (palm to face).  The Japanese version is very nicely organized AND gives much more typical examples that one might come across.  Too bad the English version is not as well written.

Comment: @A.Ellett Right? The English version feels like reading through a treatise or something, while Japanese version is straight to the point and easier to understand it because of nice examples(as you mentioned).

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky yeah, I was tod something on the line of what dROOOze said. I knew that on'yomi derives from the Chinese pronunciation and that ateji was using kanji phonetically. So it was a bit confusing, but I think I'm starting to get it now.

Comment: @vae can you add that to the question? It's difficult for people to answer if you say "I already know something about the answer" but then you don't tell us what you know.

Answer (score 4):

In simplest form, on'yomi and kun'yomi are ways of reading kanji that relate to the meaning of the character. So, for example, if 独 is referring to something being alone, then you're using either an on'yomi (e.g. doku) or a kun'yomi (e.g. hitori).

If you take a kanji's reading and use it to write another word, then that's ateji. For example, if you use 独 as the "do" in "doitsu", meaning Germany, then that's an ateji.

Comment: There are also ateji like お[土産]{みやげ} that bare little to resemblance to any standard reading.

Comment: So, on'yomi and kun'yomi are like "fixed" readings. A kanji has it's on'yomi and kun'yomi (or only one of the two categories) and if you give a kanji a reading that is not among them then that reading is an ateji?